# how do I return the latest month submission from each site in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I'm trying to update one of my pre extraction check query to ensure that all the submitters have made submissions before I extract the updated data as the final data set is something like 49 columns by 80k+rows.

Currently my test code is either a distinct list of submitters filtered for a certain year (financial year) in format YY/YY and current period (financial month) format M. I restrict the dataset which covers all submitters to the region I cover and then manually change the year or month to the correct values for the current period.

What I am hoping to do is change the code that says

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       site,
       activity_period
WHERE activity_period= '9'
  AND (site = 'site 1'
    OR site = 'site 2'
    OR site = 'site x')
  AND year = 'yy/yy';
FROM submissions
```

What I want to do is change this from having the month statement needing to be entered manually each month, into a statement that return's the max month in a given year for each of the sites in the site = statement. Then I'd order this by the month in ascending order so I can see the sites yet to submit and can chase accordingly does anyone know how I would do this.

Additionally it would be nice to know how I could set the year/month to be current period by asking for the max value that the database contains within for a separate check I'm working on that would be great.

edit notes added in changed month to activity_period so the columns make sense and added in a from statement. Edit 2 added in a couple sample tables one showing a few lines that may be in the data and the other showing what the outcome would want to show.

```
sample data
| site| value |submission month|
| --- | --- |--- |
| site 1| 40 |1|
| site 1| 40 |2|
| site 2| 5 |1|
| site 3| 400 |1|
| site 3| 409 |2|
| site 3| 4 |3|
```

output of query

```
| site| latest month received|
| ---|---|
| site 2|1|
| site 1|2|
| site 3|3|
```

I am not interested in finding any of the data (value of submission or other fields within the data I haven't put in the dummy) rather I just want to know which sites have not yet made submissions by having the sites with not having the latest month data (3 in the dummy) shown above the latest data so at a glance I can say yes I have all 18 of my sites in the latest month or not.

Comment: hey would be great if you added some sample data and sample of your intended output.  It's not super clear from the description.

Comment: sorry for slow response spent the entire day yesterday in a remote desktop and therefore never saw the notification come through. I have tried to add in a couple tables to show this which seemed to be displaying right in the preview but might have gone wrong when I hit save if you can let me know if you need these changed (if so how that be great)

Comment: much better thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just want to start by rewriting your query with `where` clause after `from`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   site,
   activity_period
FROM submissions
WHERE activity_period= '9'
  AND (site = 'site 1'
  OR site = 'site 2'
  OR site = 'site x')
  AND year = 'yy/yy';
```

If you want to only pull the "latest" month per site you can `join` the submisisons table to itself

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   site,
   activity_period
FROM submissions s
inner join (select max(year) year, site from submissions group by site) s2
  on s2.site = s.site and s2.year = s.year
WHERE activity_period= '9'
  AND (site = 'site 1'
  OR site = 'site 2'
  OR site = 'site x');
```

The query provided differs a little bit from the sample data.  Try running this to see how it works using your sample data

```
with a (site, submission, month) as( 
 select 'site 1' site, ' 40' submission,'1' month
 union all select'site 1', '40' ,'2'
 union all select 'site 2', '5' ,'1'
 union all select 'site 3', '400' ,'1'
 union all select 'site 3', '409' ,'2'
 union all select 'site 3', '4' ,'3'
 ) 
 select a.* from a
 inner join (select site, max(month) month from a group by site) a2 
   on a2.site=a.site and a2.month=a.month
```

Output is as below

```
site    submission  month
site 1  40          2
site 2  5           1
site 3  4           3
```

Explanation.  What we're doing is creating a `temporary` table that has each site and the `max` or latest month.  If we `join` this to our initial table with matching criteria on `month` and `site` we essentially filter the initial table for `latest` month per site.